# Create Apache VitualHost for each User

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I'm trying to setup a server at www.domain.com that will allow me to create hosting accounts for each user I add.

Basically my goal is to create a user and map a name-based vhost to their home dir, so:

"joe.domain.com" would point to "/home/joe"

I've tried setting up vhosts in httpd.conf but I'm not having any luck and wondering if there's a way to either 1. script this process or 2. setup some sort of variable in a generic vhost entry that will automatically create this entry.

Comment: You need to provide us with more details.  What happens when you "don't have any luck"?  Are you getting errors? Unexpected/undesired behavior? What does your configuration file look like?

Comment: Basically no matter how I configure vhosts (see below thread) I just get a 404 back. I've checked pathing, confirmed vhosts with httpd -S and everything looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the details of your setup, I can tell you that:

- Yes, you can script the process.

  Apache configuration files are just text files, so it's very easy to generate the programatically.
- Yes, you can configure some sort of generic virtual host entry.

  The [Dynamically configured mass virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html) documentation from Apache addresses this case quite nicely.

Comment: Alright, I tried the last option "Using a Separate Virtual Host Configuration File" from the link becuase that would mean only managing one map file which is ideal, and it's still not working, I get a 404 error.

Comment: So you will need to show us your configuration, and any errors in your error log.

Comment: My httpd.conf file is exactly what's on the Apach docs, then my vhosts.map has each entry as:
userx.mydomain.com /home/userx

Comment: Figured it out, needed to change 'RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ %1/docs/$1' to 'RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ %1/$1'